# Will Gatekeeper work same in Administrator Account and User Account?

Tags: gatekeeper

I heard that when using User Account, Mac asks more password and confirmation. But does this also apply to when running/installing new apps first time?

What I'd like to know is, will Gatekeeper in Administrator Account still check every new app before it is launched and ask me if I really want to use it?

I got worried that what if I end up downloading some image file that is actually hidden installer and Gatekeeper won't ask me if I want to install it (and notify me I accidentally got installer file hiding as something else) if I'm using Administrator.

Basically, will security be as tight in Administrator account than it is in User Account?

Comment: Yes! You'll need the very same Admin password to install apps from unidentified developers in both.

Comment: @owlswipe So gatekeeper security will be as tight in Admin account as it is in User account? Gatekeeper won't skip warnings in Admin account?

Comment: I always use my computer in its Admin account and am always prompted if I want to install software that isn't Apple-verified. That means: if I try to install Dropbox, I don't need a password. If I try to install a random guy's plugin app, I need to input the Admin password to install it.

Comment: I don't know about specific behind-the-scenes security stuff, so I'll refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: Happy to help! I can post that as an answer if you want...

Comment: @owlswipe It would be nice, but there is no need to trouble yourself. And by the looks of it, my current rep level means I can't vote it up and give you credit. :(